# Vue3 TypeError: template ref.value is null

Tags: templates, canvas, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, refs

how can I clean my console from the following error:

[image]

`TypeError: ref.value is null`

The error comes only with a resize event. Each time I resize the window, I render the chart. So the error message appears again and again. The documentation shows that the template ref is also initialized with a null value ([Source](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs)). So I have to do something after initialization, right?

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <canvas
    ref="chartRef"
  />
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
// ...
// on resize
export const chartRef = ref(null)
export function createChart () {
  const ctx = chartRef.value.getContext('2d')
  if (ctx !== null) { // fix me
    getDimensions()
    drawChart(ctx)
  }
}
// ...
</script>
```

How can I clean up my console so that the error message no longer appears? Thx.

Comment: Once `onMounted` and then I add an eventlistener for each resize, with a debounce of 250ms.

Comment: No, the [script setup](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md) is essential in my project. Can't do it without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option A

wrap it in a `try...catch`

### Option 2

Using a `watch`

---

I've found the best way to do it is to use a `watch`

Here is an example of a function that can be reused between multiple components. We can define a function that generates the canvas reference that can then be passed to the component - `canvasRef` .

```js
const withCanvasRef = () => {
  let onMountCallback = null;
  const onMount = callback => {
    onMountCallback = callback;
  };
  const canvasRef = ref(null);

  watch(canvasRef, (element, prevElement) => {
    if (element instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
      canvasRef.value = element;
      if (onMountCallback && prevElement === null) onMountCallback(canvasRef);
    } else {
      ctxRef.value = null;
    }
  });
  return {
    canvasRef,
    onMount
  };
};
```

We can then get the `canvasRef` in the component and pass it to the `<canvas>` element. We can also use the `onMounted` hook that the function returns to handle initial render.

```js
app.component("my-line-chart", {
  setup: props => {
    const { canvasRef, onMount } = withCanvasRef();

    const draw = () => {
      // stuff here,
      // use a check for canvasRef.value if you have conditional rendering
    };

    // on resize
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => draw());

    // on canvas mount
    onMount(() => draw());

    return { canvasRef };
  },
  template: `<div><canvas ref="canvasRef"/></div>`
});
```

See example  for example showing this in action. Hopefully you can see the benefit of using Composition API as a solution for better code reuse and organization. (Even though some aspects of it seem a bit more laborious, like having to define a watch for props manually)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const someData = Vue.ref(null);
    let t = null;

    const numPts = 20;
    const generateData = () => {
      const d = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numPts; i++) {
        d.push(Math.random());
      }

      if (someData.value == null) {
        someData.value = [...d];
      } else {
        const ref = [...someData.value];
        let nMax = 80;
        let n = nMax;
        t !== null && clearInterval(t);

        t = setInterval(() => {
          n = n -= 1;
          n <= 0 && clearInterval(t);
          const d2 = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < numPts; i++) {
            //d2.push(lerp(d[i],ref[i], n/nMax))
            d2.push(ease(d[i], ref[i], n / nMax));
          }
          someData.value = [...d2];
        }, 5);
      }
    };
    generateData();
    return { someData, generateData };
  }
});

const withCanvasRef = () => {
  let onMountCallback = null;
  const onMount = callback => {
    onMountCallback = callback;
  };
  const canvasRef = Vue.ref(null);

  Vue.watch(canvasRef, (element, prevElement) => {
    if (element instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
      canvasRef.value = element;
      if (onMountCallback && prevElement === null) onMountCallback(canvasRef);
    } else {
      ctxRef.value = null;
    }
  });
  return {
    canvasRef,
    onMount
  };
};

const drawBarGraph = (canvas, data) => {
  const width = canvas.width;
  const height = Math.min(window.innerHeight, 200);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const col1 = [229, 176, 84];
  const col2 = [202, 78, 106];

  const len = data.length;
  const mx = 10;
  const my = 10;
  const p = 4;
  const bw = (width - mx * 2) / len;

  const x = i => bw * i + p / 2 + mx;
  const w = () => bw - p;
  const h = num => (height - my * 2) * num;
  const y = num => (height - my * 2) * (1 - num) + my;
  const col = i => {
    const r = lerp(col1[0], col2[0], i / len);
    const g = lerp(col1[1], col2[1], i / len);
    const b = lerp(col1[2], col2[2], i / len);
    return `rgb(${[r, g, b]})`;
  };

  data.forEach((num, i) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = col(i);
    ctx.fillRect(x(i), y(num), w(), h(num));
  });
};

const drawLineGraph = (canvas, data) => {
  const width = canvas.width;
  const height = Math.min(window.innerHeight, 200);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const col1 = [229, 176, 84];
  const col2 = [202, 78, 106];

  const len = data.length;
  const mx = 10;
  const my = 10;
  const p = 4;
  const bw = (width - mx * 2) / len;

  const x = i => bw * i + p / 2 + mx + bw / 2;
  const y = num => (height - my * 2) * (1 - num) + my;
  const r = 2;

  const col = i => {
    const r = lerp(col1[0], col2[0], i / len);
    const g = lerp(col1[1], col2[1], i / len);
    const b = lerp(col1[2], col2[2], i / len);
    return `rgb(${[r, g, b]})`;
  };

  ctx.lineWidth = 0.2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  data.forEach((num, i) => {
    i == 0 && ctx.moveTo(x(i), y(num));
    i > 0 && ctx.lineTo(x(i), y(num));
  });
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  data.forEach((num, i) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = col(i);
    ctx.arc(x(i), y(num), r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  });
};

const drawSomething = canvas => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2 - 5;
  canvas.height = Math.min(window.innerHeight, 200);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255 241 236)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
};

app.component("my-bar-chart", {
  props: ["data"],
  setup: props => {
    const { canvasRef, onMount } = withCanvasRef();

    const draw = () => {
      if (canvasRef.value) {
        drawSomething(canvasRef.value);
        drawBarGraph(canvasRef.value, props.data);
      }
    };

    // on resize
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => draw());

    // on data change
    Vue.watch(
      () => props.data,
      () => draw()
    );

    // on canvas mount
    onMount(() => draw());

    return { canvasRef };
  },
  template: `<div><canvas ref="canvasRef"/></div>`
});

app.component("my-line-chart", {
  props: ["data"],
  setup: props => {
    const { canvasRef, onMount } = withCanvasRef();

    const draw = () => {
      if (canvasRef.value) {
        drawSomething(canvasRef.value);
        drawLineGraph(canvasRef.value, props.data);
      }
    };

    // on resize
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => draw());

    // on data change
    Vue.watch(
      () => props.data,
      () => draw()
    );

    // on canvas mount
    onMount(() => draw());

    return { canvasRef };
  },
  template: `<div><canvas ref="canvasRef"/></div>`
});

app.mount("#app");

const lerp = (start, end, amt) => (1 - amt) * start + amt * end;
const ease = (start, end, amt) => {
  return lerp(start, end, Math.sin(amt * Math.PI * 0.5));
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.chart {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="generateData">Scramble</button>
  <div>
    <my-bar-chart class="chart" :data="someData"></my-bar-chart>
    <my-line-chart class="chart" :data="someData"></my-line-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it looks really promising. I'll will give it a try. I'm sorry if it's gonna take a little.

Answer (score 32):

I am a bit too late, but I faced the same issue with Vue 3. I solved juste by returning the reference :

```html
<template>
  <input ref="myinput">
</template>


<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {

    const myinput = ref(null) // Assign dom object reference to "myinput" variable

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(myinput.value) // Log a DOM object in console
    })

    return { myinput } // WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT THIS
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but [it is the same as the documentation for the Composition API says](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html). I am using the experimental `script setup` version in my case unfortunately.

Comment: That you need to return it solved it for me as well!

Comment: When using the script setup in combination with data that is getting fetched, I had to wait until the data was available. I.e. I only accessed the ref once it was not null anymore.

Answer (score 16):

If you're seeing the `yourRef.value` as `null` then maybe the element you're trying to get the `ref` to is inside a false `v-if`. Vue will not instantiate the `ref` until the element is actually required.

Comment: Thank you, I was confused when the element seems inconsistent in value

Comment: This was the problem I had. Solved it by using :class with Bootstraps d-none and d-block instead of using v-if.

Answer (score 4):

Scratched my head for a while over this, but basically, when using `<script setup>`, the public instance of the component that is exposed (when retrieved from template refs) won't expose any of the bindings declared inside.

If you want them exposed, use [defineExpose()](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose).

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    const a = 1
    const b = ref(2)

    defineExpose({
        a,
        b
    })
</script>
```

It's a compiler macro, so you don't need to import it.

Comment: how does this work with the resize problem he(and I) are struggling with? I tried to add it after the declaration like your show, but it still gives the error when I try to use the 'b' for a resize using: "  onMounted (() => {
    function onWindowResize() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
       b.value.textContent = 'resize'
      })
    }
    onWindowResize()
  })"

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late too, but considering it's for Vue 3 and it's still 2021 here is my solution for those who are not using `Composition API`:

In one of sub-components, I had something like this:

```html
<div ref='popupMenu'>
... some content here ...
</div>
```

As expected, `this.$refs.popupMenu` was set in `mounted` and `activated` callbacks, however, for whatever reason, when I attempted to approach it from a window scroll listener, it was set to `null`. I've consoled out entire component to see what's going on, and I could see `$refs.popupMenu` was `null`.

Not sure if it was something I did, or maybe my misunderstanding on how mount/activate works when you have parent component also doing re-rendering of it's subcomponents, but what worked out for me was:

Template

```html
<div :ref='storeReference'>
.... popup content here ...
</div>
```

Data

```js
data() {
    popupMenu: null
}
```

Methods

```js
methods: {
    storeReference(e) {
        if(e) {
            this.popupMenu = e;
        }
    }
    clearReference(e) {
        this.popupMenu = null;
    }
}
```

This would ensure I keep the reference in all times, and worked well in my case.

Would have a method `clearReference` when control is `unmounted` or `deactivated` that would set `this.popupMenu = null` so it does not keep it in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to use the reference in the `onBeforeMount` function. Obviously, that doesn't work, I can only use it once the component is rendered because that's when the reference is set.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same error message when trying to reference a component to use one of its inner properties in a computed function.  The ref wasn't ready to be used during the mount by the computed evaluation.  Fix was adding the ? to the .value to treat null ref value as false.

```
<template>
   <ChartComponent ref="chartRef" />
   <button v-if="showButton">Label</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
   const chartRef = ref<any>(null)
   const showButton = computed(() => chartRef.value?.chartProperty)
</script>
```