# Viewport change of Vue3 app in Cypress gives TypeError ref.value is null

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, cypress

In Cypress I am changing the viewport of my Veu3 app after I preform any other test and it gives the error: "(uncaught execption)  TypeError a.value is null".

The minimum app that produces the error:

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  const a = ref(null)
  
  onMounted (() => {
    function onWindowResize() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        //a.value always needs to refresh when the window resizes to different content
        a.value.textContent = 'Text displayed here will be decided on the window size'
      })
    }
    onWindowResize()
  })
</script>

<template>
<div>
  <span ref="a" data-testid="test1">M</span>
  <a> ..more</a>
</div>
</template>
```

With the following test. The interesting thing to note here is that if you don't include the first test the Error is not there.

```js
import Test from '../Test.vue'

describe('run 2 test', () => {
  it('The error only appears if I run a test before I run the viewport change', () => {
    cy.mount(Test)
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').get('a').should('contain', ' ..more')
  })

  it('The error originates on the first viewport changes it appears', () => {
    cy.mount(Test)
//so it appears here
    cy.viewport(550, 750)

    let charCount = 0
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').then(($span) => {
      charCount = String($span.text()).length;
    })
    cy.viewport(400, 400)
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').then(($span) => {
      const newCharCount = String($span.text()).length;
      expect(newCharCount).to.be.eq(charCount)
    })
  })
})
```

I found [this anwser to the question: "Vue3 TypeError ref.value is null"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74267819/1735311) and tried adding `defineExpose()` yet it doesn't change a thing. I tried re-declaring the `const a = ref(null)` within the `onMounted()` also no luck. Been searching but can't find a solution any help would be appreciated since a lot of the test will revolve around viewport changes.

The error causes the rest of the application, which depends on the a.value to fail.

**UPDATE**
Apparently it is me who can't see what is wrong. So, I would like to understand why a.value should not exist in unMounted() (even thought this is an [example in de Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted)). Also why it does work in de browser without any errors. And why does it work in Cypress is no tests precede the test?

I would really like to understand and find a way around this.

Comment: Just a comment - `cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').get('a')` is not really effective, since the two `.get()`s are disconnected. If you want to incorporate a traversal in the query, it would be `cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').next('a')` since `<a>` is a sibling of `<span>`. Not that it causes the problem, but just saying you may not be running the query you expect.

Comment: THX, will take note:)

Comment: The solution given by @Aladin Spaz doesn't take in to account that the value of `a.value.textContext` needs to be updated on every occasion.  It just stops updating it. 

In the Vue Docs https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted the example that is given of the use of `onMounted()` is exactly what I am doing here without the eventListener. Also the text does pass in Cypress if no test precedes the test....

Comment: That makes no sense - you can't update an element that does not exist!

Comment: I don;t understand why the element doesn't exist. could you explain? https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted here it shows the same situation as an example. Furthermore why does it work without errors if there is no test preceding this test?

Comment: @TesterDick I am sorry I am not seeing it. It must be me since everyone seems to agree. but especially the fact that it passes if no test precedes it makes that I can't see why it does exist the first time around and not the second time.

Comment: @TesterDick and I realized this now, why does it work in the browser without any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the versions of cypress that you're using or how you run it, but what I did to reproduce your problem was to use vue 3, and cypress 13, and run the test with this command `cypress run --component --headed --no-exit --browser chrome`. And the error that I found is `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')`.

### What happened

Assuming my way of reproducing is correct, I can assure you that the error that you found "`TypeError ref.value is null`" is actually happening on the first test, not the second test. Want some proof? try to use these codes:

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  const a = ref(null)
  const props = defineProps(['testname'])

  onMounted (() => {
    function onWindowResize() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        //a.value always needs to refresh when the window resizes to different content
        try {
          a.value.textContent = 'Text displayed here will be decided on the window size'
          console.log(`success changing textContent on ${props.testname}`)
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
          console.log(`error happens on ${props.testname}`)
        }
      })
    }
    onWindowResize()
  })
</script>

<template>
<div>
  <span ref="a" data-testid="test1">M</span>
  <a> ..more</a>
</div>
</template>
```

```
describe('run 2 test', () => {
  it('The error only appears if I run a test before I run the viewport change', () => {
    cy.mount(Test, { props: { testname: "test1" } })
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').get('a').should('contain', ' ..more')
  })

  it('The error originates on the first viewport changes it appears', () => {
    cy.mount(Test, { props: { testname: "test2" } })
    //so it appears here
    cy.viewport(550, 750)

    let charCount = 0
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').then(($span) => {
      charCount = String($span.text()).length;
    })
    cy.viewport(400, 400)
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').then(($span) => {
      const newCharCount = String($span.text()).length;
      expect(newCharCount).to.be.eq(charCount)
    })
  })
})
```

If you run with those codes, you'll see clearly that the error happens on the first test:

[image: cypress error viewport change]

### Why

So why exactly did that happen? It seems like when the first test finishes, the component doesn't get unmounted, even after the second test starts to run, want some proof? try to update the script setup to this:

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue'
  const a = ref(null)
  const props = defineProps(['testname'])

  function intervalFunction() {
    console.log(`running on ${props.testname}`)
  }
  onMounted (() => {
    setInterval(intervalFunction, 1000);
    function onWindowResize() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        //a.value always needs to refresh when the window resizes to different content
        try {
          a.value.textContent = 'Text displayed here will be decided on the window size'
          console.log(`success changing textContent on ${props.testname}`)
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
          console.log(`error happens on ${props.testname}`)
        }
      })
    }
    onWindowResize()
  })

  onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    clearInterval(intervalFunction)
  })
</script>
```

Now run the test again, and on the console, you'll see that the interval prints don't stop even when it should be cleared on the `onBeforeUnmount` lifecycle hook and after the test is finished.

[image: cypress mount]

That would only mean that the component persists and is still affected by the next test. In other words, when this line `cy.viewport(550, 750)` is executed, it doesn't just affect the component mounting on the second test, but also the first one. This is just my hunch, but for some reason, the first component isn't unmounted properly (the component has no more elements after the first test is done, but maybe some of it is still there and cypress somehow still affects it)

So why is it like that? to be honest i'm not sure myself, but i'd say that error is a false alarm for the test, because that error happens when the test (the first one) is already executed, so in my opinion, you can just ignore it. If you feel uncomfortable with the error, you could just wrap the value assignment inside a try catch like what I show above.

Or maybe you can unmount the component by following [this guide](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/17959).

## EDIT

Actually, after some tweaking, you simply need to remove the window resize event listener when unmounting:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue";
const a = ref(null);

function resizeCallback() {
  //a.value always needs to refresh when the window resizes to different content
  a.value.textContent = "Text displayed here will be decided on the window size";
}

onMounted(() => {
  function onWindowResize() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCallback);
  }
  onWindowResize();
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeCallback);
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <span ref="a" data-testid="test1">M</span>
    <a> ..more</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This explains it all. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

When I use a ref in React, it's always good practice to check the `ref.value` before accessing/assigning it.

So if I put a guard inside the resize listener, the error

> (uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')

goes away.

```html
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  const a = ref(null)
  
  onMounted (() => {
    function onWindowResize() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {

        // check that the ref is linked to the element before using it
        if (a.value) {
          a.value.textContent = 'resize'
        }
      })
    }
    onWindowResize()
  })
</script>
```

Was not sure if the logic of the test still holds, though, because it may be throwing away a resize event.

So I added a check for the text "resize" (which is set by the listener), and it passes.

The rest of your test doesn't pass, which follows because now the resizer is functioning.

```js
it('The error originates on the first viewport changes it appears', () => {
  cy.mount(Test)

  cy.viewport(550, 750)

  let charCount = 0
  cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').then(($span) => {

    charCount = $span.text().length; 

    cy.viewport(400, 400)

    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]')
      .should('have.text', 'resize')               // passes
      .then(($span) => {
        const newCharCount = $span.text().length;
        expect(newCharCount).to.be.eq(charCount)   // now failing because resize occurred
      })
  })
})
```

[image]

Also, there's a warning in the dev console that the `resize` event is being deprecated and will be removed (chrome browser).

It suggests

> Consider using MutationObserver instead.

Comment: Hi Aladin, thank you so much for this. but the problem is that the variable ALWAYS needs to be accessed when the window is resized. Just not using it is it is not defined is not an option, it needs to be defined. I will look at this MutationObserver, and changes accordingly thanks!

Comment: The basic problem is the template `<span ref="a" data-testid="test1">M</span>` needs to set the `ref.value` before the app is allowed to go live. In React it's possible to use different hooks to ensure that happens, but with Vue3 the equivalent API is not so clear. I'm sure there's a way to do it, but finding it would be the problem.

Comment: BTW `MutationObserver` won't solve it per-se.

Comment: I will try tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: When the window resizes it needs to calculate the amount of characters it needs to display. You also helped with the Cypress test for that in another question;) there is a `onUpdated()` hook https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onupdated

Comment: You still haven't said what goes wrong with the `onMounted()` solution. Surely it does not make sense to try to resize an element that does not yet exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255596/discussion-between-st-jan-and-aladin-spaz).

Comment: as var as I know the element does exist within the `onMounted()` hook

Comment: The `ref.value` id attatched to the element, when Vue adds it to the DOM it sets the `ref.value`. So if the value is undefined, the element does not exist yet.

Comment: I am not following you, could you elaborate a bit more? https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted here it shows this situation as an example (without the EventListner). Also I don't get why it would work without a preceding test and not when there is a test infront of it.

Comment: I am sorry I am not seeing it, it must be me since everyone seems to agree. I would really like to understand so I can fix it.

Comment: O and I realized this now, it does work in the browser without any errors. Just not in Cypress when I first run another test.

Answer (score 7):

I think your test is the wrong way round, if the resize changes the text so `expect(newCharCount).to.be.eq(charCount)` would not pass, because now the char count is larger. See `a.value.textContent = ...`

Did you make a typo there?

```js
    let charCount = 0
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').then(($span) => {
      charCount = String($span.text()).length;
    })
    cy.viewport(400, 400)
    cy.get('[data-testid="test1"]').then(($span) => {
      const newCharCount = String($span.text()).length;
      expect(newCharCount).to.be.gt(charCount)     <-- size has increased 
    })
```

---

Adding a guard is the correct action to stop the `uncaught:exception`.

Window resize works independently of the Vue app, the error is occuring after the component is unmounted.

Adding some debugging:

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

  const el = ref(null)
  
  let isMounted = false

  onMounted (() => {
    isMounted = true
    console.log('Mounted: ref el', el.value, isMounted)
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      if (isMounted) {
        el.value.textContent = 'some new text'
      }
    })
  })

  onUnmounted (() => {
    isMounted = false
    console.log('Unmounted: ref el', el.value, isMounted)
  })
</script>
```

Console:

- Mounted: ref el <span data-testid=​"test1">​M​​ true
- Unmounted: ref el null false
- Mounted: ref el <span data-testid=​"test1">​some new text​​ true

Shows ref `el` is pointing at the span when mounted (as expected).

Technically in `onBeforeUnmount()` you should ***remove the listener*** and that will also get rid of the `uncaught:exception`.

Since resize listener is deprecated, change it to MutationObserver instead.

Alternatively, use [useElementSize from @vueuse/core](https://vueuse.org/core/useElementSize/).